# Read Serial Reply After Write With C#

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, serial-port

Is it possible to read the reply from a serial port right after sending a command in C#?  I have a stepper motor driver and am trying to read the current step number and display it in the status bar of my C# Windows form program with the .net framework 4.0.  To do this I need to send the "RC" command.  The driver then sends back the number.  My question is this:  How do you read the serial reply immediately after writing to the serial port?  Any help with this would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, call `ReadLine()`.

There's an issue however, serial ports are glacially slow.  A common baudrate setting is 9600 baud, each character takes one millisecond to get received.  Say you get 6 digits back, you're looking at RC + lf + 000000 + lf + controller overhead milliseconds.  Your program is dead to the world for at least 10 milliseconds.  The equivalent of about 20 million cpu cycles.

Whether that's a real problem entirely depends on how many cpu cycles you need in your app.  You solve it by using threading, either explicitly with a thread that does nothing but talking to the controller or by using the DataReceived event.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the ReadExisting Method which includes a combo of stream and buffer. Without knowing specifics I highly recommend checking MSDN docs here

[SerialPort Class (System.IO.Ports)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)